# Why my import MessageUI in AppDelegate is not visible within my UITableViewController?

Tags: swift, import, messageui

Since Swift files are visible for each others, why my import within Appelegate is not visible for one of my controllers? I get an error there.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `Use of undeclared type MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: on which line of your .swift file are you declaring `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`?  show me.

Comment: line 14: `class PBOUserViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {`

Comment: And you added an "`import MessageUI`" at the top of the file, after all the other imports?

Comment: inside my `AppDelegate.swift` file: `import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
import MessageUI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Access level for Swift Modules. Default access level for Swift modules is internal, that is to that file itself.

Have a look here in Apple documentation [Access level in Swift module](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29)

You need to import frameworks/modules in which ever class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Put `import MessageUI` at the top of the file where you declare your `PBOUserViewController` class (which I hope is contained in a separate .swift file than your AppDelegate).